# "setprop ro.product.model" not working

Tags: android

I am using below command to set property, but getting an error. Please help.

Adb shell setprop ro.product.model "Ino5"
setprop: failed to set property 'ro.product.model' to "Ino5"

Comment: I resolved the problem by rebooting the device

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have root access, you can't change the value of the props. This applies to (AFAIK) all the props available. If you don't have root, you can't change the value.

However, if you have root, make sure you call `su` first:

```
adb shell su
adb shell setprop [prop] [value]
```

## EDIT

Since it still doesn't work, my theory is that it's dependent on the shell instance. So instead, do this:

```
adb shell
su
setprop [prop] [val]
```

Doing `adb shell` creates a local instance where as `adb shell [command]` executes a single command. The next commands are then done within the ADB shell without the need to call `adb shell` first.

Comment: Thank you Zoe for your response. I have root access, and I have called Su first, I got a pop-up notification that Superuser rights have been granted. After that I have applied command same as you have mentioned. But even after that getting the same error.

Comment: any suggestions on how can i change ro.product.model ? I tried the answer above but no success. Thanks!